# Preventing the console from entering whitespace (i.e. space, tab, and newline) in the ch character (in c++)

Tags: c++, character, user-input, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I want to prevent the console from entering **whitespace (i.e. space, tab and newline)** in the center code hereh character (in **c++**). i have tried the condition **((!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) || (!(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))** in the do-while loop as shown in the code but it isn't working. Kindly help me if anyone has any knowledge about this.

**Following is my code (in c++):**

```
char ch;
cout << "Enter the character: ";
cin >> ch;
do
{
    cout << "Invalid input.\n";
    cout << "Re-enter the character: ";
    cin >> ch;  
} while((!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) || (!(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'));
```

Comment: `(!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) || (!(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))` will always be true because no characters are lowercase while they are uppercase.

Comment: Moreover, the code will display "Invalid input" even if the input was valid in the beginning because you are using a `do-while` loop.

Comment: Also your `do-while` statement is invalid because one `)` is missing between `'Z'))` and `;`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but there are character encodings ([EBCDIC](http://ascii-table.com/ebcdic-table.php) for one) that stick non-alphabetic characters inside the range of values `['a' .. 'z']` and inside the range of values `['A' .. 'Z']`, so `ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'` can be true for non-lowercase characters. Use `std::islower` and `std::isupper` to test for lower and upper case, or `std::isalpha` to check for alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> ch;` will skip whitespace characters, so just remove the `do-while` part.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uWVpzCtao26Kr1K1):

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(){
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter the character: ";
    cin >> ch;
    cout << (int)ch << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
 a
```

output:

```
Enter the character: 97
```

You can see that the whitespace character before `a` is skipped.